# How to hide error message on ng-blur using angular material?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

How to invoke `-ng-blur` if user lose focus from element or field , i tried to use angular `ng-blur` but its not working for me , any idea how to achieve this or any better approach when user lose focus from input field ?

main.html

```
<md-input-container flex="100">
    <md-chips flex="100" ng-model="notifyCtrl.cc" name="email"
              placeholder="Add Cc" md-separator-keys="customKeys" 
              md-transform-chip="addChips($chip)" ng-blur="blurCc()">
    </md-chips>
    <p style="color:red" ng-show="patternError">An email must contain a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or _ characters</p>
</md-input-container>
```

Ctrl.js

```
$scope.blurCc = function() {
        $scope.patternError = false;
        console.log('blur called');
      }
```

Comment: I guess you already double checked it but : does md-chips component supports `ng-blur` ?

Comment: even it does not work on `md-input-container`, is there any work around ?

Comment: Just to be sure, what version of Angular Material are you using?

Comment: we are using angular 1.5

Comment: And which version of Angular Material ?

Comment: angular material 1.1.4

Comment: The `blur` event is intercepted by the  `input` element inside the `<md-chips>` component. If your goal is to add custom validations, use the hooks provided by the [ngModelController API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms (Custom Validation)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation). [D](https://plnkr.co/edit/GvgMA33RL9J0pUeZ1oXW?p=preview)